# How can I check whether innerHTML is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, class

so i am trying to set a Class on a Parent Element (Section), when the second Child Div innerHTML is empty.

So for example: (This Section should get a class of "hide-section" to hide it)

```
<section class="ef-area">
   <div class="child-1">
       <div class="child-2">
       </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

This one should not be hidden because "child-2" is not empty

```
<section class="ef-area">
   <div class="child-1">
      <div class="child-2">
         <div class="child-3">
            ...//What Ever
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I looped over all "ef-area" sections but how can i set only those sections to display = none when the second child (child-2) is empty.

What I did is:

```
    let efAreaDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".ef-area > div > div");
  
    for (singleDiv of efAreaDivs) {
    
    if (singleDiv.innerHTML == "") {
      singleDiv.closest("section").classList.add("hide-section");
    }
```

The class "hide-section" never gets set.

I think js always ignores it, because there are singleDiv´s that are not empty or am I wrong?

Comment: `<div class="child-2">
       </div>` isn't empty - it has a newline character and spaces ... `<div class="child-2"></div>` is empty ... try `if (singleDiv.innerHTML.trim() == "") {`

Comment: I assume that your condition is triggering, you can console.log("Test"); to see if it responds properly, I assume it does though; which leads me to your singleDiv.closest("section"). You can do parentElement twice?

Comment: An alternative, depending on your definition of "empty" (if it doesn't have any child divs, ignoring text) and tagged [tag:jquery] is to use `.children()` eg `if ($(singleDiv).children() === 0) $(singleDiv).addClass("hide-section")` - this could be more efficient, but shows the concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content of `<div class="child-2">` below

```
<section class="ef-area">
   <div class="child-1">
       <div class="child-2">
       </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

is **NOT** an empty string ... it is `"\n      "`

You need to trim the innerHTML (which get's rid of whitspace at the beginning and end of the string, in this case everything)

```
if (singleDiv.innerHTML.trim() == "") {
   singleDiv.closest("section").classList.add("hide-section");
}
```